# AttributeError: has no attribute 'STATIC'

Tags: python, django, pycharm, attributes

So have been trying to start my server on Python (I'm new to Python, Django) and below is my code to run my server which can be seen here https://shrib.com/#Meerkat9GKd1xx
and when I run the code I get the attribute error below:

```py
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)+static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC.ROOT)

AttributeError: module 'student_management_system.settings' has no attribute 'STATIC'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please share your `settings.py` file ?

Comment: https://shrib.com/#StripedSkunk4zMrx42 here is the settings.py

Comment: It seems like everything is perfect in your `settings.py`. can you please share your `urls.py` file?

Comment: Here is the url.py https://shrib.com/#CivetCat9p6pLxA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it on your `settings.py` file and `urls.py` file as like below :

settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked then i got "did you install mysqlclient" which i did.

Comment: Which i think have been able to fix. Thanks alot once again!!